# Formatting string in angular expression

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app, I want to display a value:

```
<div>{{myValue}}</div>
```

I also want to make it display "Empty" if the value is empty, like so:

```
<div>{{myValue || 'Empty'}}</div>
```

How can I make myValue be formatted normally, but 'Empty' be italicized?

Comment: need to use `ng-bind-html` directive if you want to add HTML to the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use an `ng-if` to handle the two cases:

HTML Template:

```
<div ng-if="myValue">{{myValue}}</div>
<div ng-if="!myValue"><i>Empty</i></div>  <!-- css here! -->
```

However, this can be a bit verbose.  If you have this occurring again and again, use a `filter` or bind `ng-bind-html` from a controller function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show`/`ng-hide`:

```
<div ng-show="myValue">{{myValue}}</div>
<div ng-hide="myValue"><i>Empty</i></div>
```

These directives take "truthy" values and shows/hides according to the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

One angular way , is to use ng-bind-html

```
  <body ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
    <p ng-bind-html="myValue"></p>
  </body>
```

Within controller, you manage emptyness condition:

```
app.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
  if($scope.myValue == ''){
    $scope.myValue = '<i>Empty</i>';
  }
}]);
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWkoduUdHzAdQLVbPhSJ?p=preview)

HTH